# Can I use attr_accessible for PayPal IPN in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I used this RailsCast to create part of a shopping cart system, http://railscasts.com/episodes/142-paypal-notifications

There is a piece of code there that is called by PayPal for notification.

```
def create
  PaymentNotification.create!(:params => params, :cart_id => params[:invoice], :status => params[:payment_status], :transaction_id => params[:txn_id])
  render :nothing => true
end
```

I tried it on Heroku, and there were no warnings and no errors. The PaymentNotification object was created successfully in the database - but everything was nil except for the id! I opened the heroku console and tried:

```
irb(main):002:0> PaymentNotification.create!(:cart_id => "2", :status => "Complete", :transaction_id => "XYZXYZXYZXYZXYZ")
< => "2", :status => "Complete", :transaction_id => "XYZXYZXYZXYZXYZ")
```

Which gave me this,

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: cart_id, status, transaction_id
```

Why didn't this warning come up in the Heroku logs? Why was it created successfully anyway (is it because it's just a warning, and not an error?)

Can I just use attr_accessible for these things? The notification has to be validated anyway (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside)

Answer (score 1):

For app security, you must add `attr_accessible` to your attributes.

On rails 4 is added this gem https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters. Also

I recomend to you use adaptive payments. You can take a look to this post:

[Paypal Adaptive Payment for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451587/paypal-adaptive-payment-for-ruby/14456484#14456484)

Comment: Adding attr_accessible makes it less secure, not more secure I thought. Because without attr_accessible, all the params are by default not available for mass-assignment.

Comment: You can take a look to http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-7-mass-assignment-security/#.UQBkUEhKhO0